# How to scrape the href tags with a certain class?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape names from this website: https://athletics.baruch.cuny.edu/sports/mens-swimming-and-diving/roster . When I inspect the element, I get that the name shows up between h3 tags, using an a tag and an href with a class of "sidearm-sports-file-link-read sidearm-sports-file-link-processed"..

Here is my code to get the scraped names:

```
page = requests.get('https://athletics.baruch.cuny.edu/sports/mens-swimming-and-diving/roster')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
names = soup.find_all('h3', class_ = "sidearm-sports-file-link-read sidearm-sports-file-link- 
processed")
print(names)
```

When I try to print the names, it shows up as an empty list. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I believe the problem is that it's a dynamic web page, meaning you are trying to access html that hasn't been loaded in yet. It is better to use selenium in this instance.

Comment: Always search the static page source for your selector. If it's not there, BS won't find it either. JS is injecting it dynamically. See [Web-scraping JavaScript page with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python/)

Answer (score 0):

the class you're searching is the one of the `a`s inside the headings. and you need to set a user-agent to access the page

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0; Windows NT 5.0; Trident/5.1)'}
url='https://athletics.baruch.cuny.edu/sports/mens-swimming-and-diving/roster'
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
names = soup.select('h3 a')
print(names)
```